# Adding properties file entry to the class path entry of the manifest file in java

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have a properties file in the resources folder in my project. I have created a JAR file by excluding this properties file, so that any changes made to the properties file will reflect in my JAR file. Now I want to include this properties file path in the class path entry of my manifest file. How can I do this?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so can you accept it? If not can you please post what you did? This will help others, like me, who also stumbled upon this issue and want to know if the given solution is viable. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should put the file in a folder and refer it from the manifest.
So, I have the manifest entry of my.jar:

```
Class-Path: prop/
```

Then I have a folder "prop" near the my.jar and .properties file in in.
Seems it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply kan. As I mentioned, I have a resources folder, in which the properties file is placed. I tried to do this   ' Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.main.Main
Class-path: ./resources/label.properties ./lib/jogl.jar ./lib/gluegen-rt.jar '    I tried to include resources/ in the classpath entry but it doesnt recognize. How can I proceed?

Comment: There is a small sample, it works for me. Run it with `java -jar so7900638.jar`. http://files.rsdn.ru/20380/so7900638.zip